# How to call window developed in C# through FindWindow api

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi, xaml

I am new to C# and xaml code. I have one sample code which implemented in C#. when I have reviewed xaml file I got `<Window x:Class="test.MainWindow">`.

So does `test.MainWindow` indicate the class name for this window.

I am trying to invoke this window from other application which is developed in win 32.
I am trying to pass this class name to `FindWindow("test.MainWindow",NULL)` ,but it fails. does anything missing over there.

how I can change the class name of window developed in C#?

Thanks,

Sagar

Comment: A Windows window class name is not the same thing as a WPF class name.  The one that FindWindow looks for is auto-generated and unpredictable in WPF.  Don't go there.

Comment: What does "invoke this window" mean?

Comment: @Hans :so what is role of x:Class? @David : Scenario is like this . application developed in C# will be running on screen say A and Another application developed in win 32 say B will get the handle of window from A and will change the windows width and height. for that I need to use findwindow. which takes either class name or window title. as I am looking to pass class name that I am getting from x:Class it is getting failed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FindWindow` wont recognize xaml class name.

Try to use

```
<Window x:Class="test.MainWindow" Title="MyTestWindow">

FindWindow(NULL,"MyTestWindow");
```

Comment: Thanks Stecya .. yes it works this way. but how we can make use of class?

Comment: If you see classname in spy++ it was someting like `HwndWrapper[MyTestWindow.exe;;5584536b-29d3-4e24-91df-7eef5b0aee6d]` with random Guid, so i think its impossible to determine its class name

Comment: Yes Stecya its getting something like this. seems like we need to add regular expression in FindWindow api.

Answer (score 0):

You can try navigating through the windows of your C# program by usuing the tool Spy++ in visual studio tools and retrieve the name of your main window, child windows, and so on.

Comment: Thanks yms.cu I tried with spy++ , everytime I get different class name. seems like x.Class serves different purpose.